# How to use homogeneity, continuity and L'Hopital's rule to prove $F(0,L) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I have the following problem:

> Consider $F:= \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $F_{K}(K,L), F_{L}(K,L)>0$  and $F_{KK}(K,L), F_{LL}(K,L)<0$ for all $K,L$. It also holds that $F$ is homogeneous of degree one. Moreover, the Inada Conditions hold, i.e. \begin{equation}\lim\limits_{K \rightarrow 0}F_{K} = \lim\limits_{L \rightarrow 0}F_{L} = +\infty \end{equation} and \begin{equation} \lim\limits_{K \rightarrow \infty}F_{K} = \lim\limits_{L \rightarrow \infty}F_{L} = 0 \end{equation} Show that $F(0,L) = 0$ for all $L$.

Now, my attempt:

From the Euler Theorem, we know that $F$ is such that \begin{equation}
F(K,L) = K\cdot F_{K}(K,L) + L \cdot F_{L}(K,L)
\end{equation}

From the differentiability of $F$ and the fact that the partial derivatives are homogeneous of degree zero, we can write \begin{gather}
F(0,L) = \lim_{K\rightarrow 0}F(K,L) = \lim_{K\rightarrow 0}\frac{F_{K}(K,L)}{1/K} + L \cdot \lim_{K\rightarrow 0}  F_{L}\left(\frac{L}{K}\right)\\
\end{gather}

Using the Inada Conditions, $\lim_{K\rightarrow 0} F_{L}\left(\frac{L}{K}\right) = 0$ because it is as if $L$ was increasing, in this case because we are dealing with an homogenous function of degree zero. By L'Hopital's rule, we can compute \begin{equation}
\lim_{K\rightarrow 0}\frac{F_{K}(K,L)}{1/K} = \lim_{K\rightarrow 0}\frac{F_{KK}(K,L)}{-1/K^2} = 0
\end{equation}

Hence, $F(0,L) = 0$ as disered.

My doubt is on the last step. I understand that the second derivative involved, although not constant over $K$, is bounded over $K$. So, I can take the given limit. Is it wrong? Any ideas of an alternative proof?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $F(0,L)=LF(0,1)$. Furthermore, $F(0,1)=\lim_{L\to\infty}F(0,K/L)=\lim_{L\to\infty}F(K,L)/L$. By L'Hopital's rule, $\lim_{L\to\infty}F(K,L)/L=\lim_{L\to\infty}F_L(K,L)=0$. Hence, $F(0,L)=LF(0,1)=0$.